# Make array repeat when got IndexError

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, circular-list

I want an array to loop when the code throws the IndexError. 
Here is the Example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

a[x] -> output
0 -> 1
1 -> 2
...
4 -> 5
after except IndexError
5 -> 1
6 -> 2
...
9 -> 5
10 -> IndexError (Should be 1)
```

My code works but when pos > 9 it still throws the IndexError.

```
pos = 5
try:
    a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    print(a[pos])
except IndexError:
    print(a[pos - len(a)])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a circular iterator, use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle). If you just want circular behaviour when indexing, you can use modulo-based indexing.

```
In [20]: a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [21]: pos = 9

In [22]: a[pos % len(a)]
Out[22]: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because when `pos > 4 and pos < 10` your code throws an IndexError exception, and it then runs `a[pos - len(a)]` which will give the desired result.

However, when `pos >= 10`, the control will go to the Except block, but then the statement `a[pos - len(a)]` will also give an IndexError exception, becuase `pos - len(a)` would be greater than 4, since len(a) is a constant.

I would recommend you to implement a circular iterator about which coldspeed said in his answer, or do something like this if you want to follow your approach:

```
except IndexError:
    print(a[pos % len(a)])
```

P.S. You also don't need to put this whole thing in a try-except block. ^.^

Comment: Nit: Using modulo based indexing does not make your list a circular iterator, it only lets you index your list in a circular fashion. Also, you don't have to put your indexing code inside a try/except.

Comment: Oops. I was talking about the `itertools.cycle`. Gotta brush up me English 'mate. I just wrote how OP could implement this in his "algorithm", the try-except approach.

Answer (score 0):

You want to print `a[pos % len(a)]`, not `a[pos - len(a)]`, as anything greater than 10, minus 5, is greater than 5.